# Linking.svc URL in SDL Web 8

Tags: content-delivery, web8, odata, installation, linking

I am in the process of adapting my web app which uses the OData endpoints of Tridion 2013 to use the new endpoints offered by SDL Web 8.

My old app used these two URLs to access the Tridion 2013 linking and content services respectively

- https://my.tridion2013.server/linking.svc
- https://my.tridion2013.server/odata.svc

I am able to retrieve content from the SDL Web 8 server using the following URL

- http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/client/v2/content.svc

I am now trying to figure out the URL for the new Content Service Linking API which is [documented here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A087EB01-1A59-4A02-A6D7-D70EB7336DB3&addHistory=true&query=linking.svc&scope=&tid=95282fd6-ad5e-4e56-bc72-af033196155f&filename=GUID-A087EB01-1A59-4A02-A6D7-D70EB7336DB3.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A087EB01-1A59-4A02-A6D7-D70EB7336DB3&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dlinking.svc&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1467659779537&currentQuery=linking.svc&currentScope=). The specific extract that has me confused is this:

> The linking commands are exposed under the URL /linking.svc/ relative
>   to the root of the Content Service.

Does this mean my linking service will be at this URL?

- http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/client/v2/content.svc/linking.svc

When I try to use that, I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code></code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">Property 'linking' cannot be requested, there was no resource selected</message>
</error>
```

Any suggestions for what this URL should be would be greatly appreciated, or what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/client/v2/linking.svc

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov, yup get a 404 with the default "Whitelabel Error Page"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking service is moved to root of the content service. You can access it like

```
 http://my.sdlweb8.server:86/linking
```

For example to get Component link

```
http://localhost:8081/linking/componentLink?sourcePageURI='<id>'&targetComponentURI='<id>'&excludeTemplateURI='<id>'....
```

Comment: you are my hero. I guess this is a documentation defect as the docs imply that you should use the ".svc" extension. I will add it to the doc portal.

Comment: Also dynamic Link can work like this - http://localhost:8081/linking/dynamicComponentLink?targetPageURI=tcm:9-10935-64&targetComponentURI=tcm:9-10952-16&targetTemplateURI=tcm:9-1279-32&linkTagAttributes=%27id=1%27&linkText=DynamicLink which should return HTM link text "DynamicLink". 
Source will have resolved url to link to the TargetComponentUri.